# PHPUnit mock class that has named static constructor

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, dependencies, phpunit

Given I have a `FruitSalad` class (the system under test):

```
class FruitSalad
{
    protected $fruits = [];

    public function addFruit(Fruit $fruit)
    {
        $this->fruits[] = $fruit;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And I have a `Fruit` class:

```
class Fruit
{
    public static function withName($name)
    {
        $instance = new MyDependencyClass();
        $instance->name = $name;
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

A trivial example, however you can see that the `Fruit` class uses a named static constructor, and the `addFruit()` method on the `FruitSalad` class type hints `Fruit` as its expected parameter.

When writing a test for `addFruit()`, I need to mock the `Fruit` class.

```
function test_it_can_add_a_fruit_to_its_list_of_fruits()
{
    $fruit = $this->getMockBuilder('Fruit')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $this->fruitSalad->addFruit($fruit);
    // Do some assertion.
}
```

This creates a simple mock of the `Fruit` class, but I want to instantiate it via the `withName()` static method - and I do not want to expose a setter for the `name` property.

How can I create a mock for `Fruit` using the static named constructor?

Comment: Do you want to mock `withName`? If it should initiate the `Fruit` object, a static method is the wrong choice, use `__construct` instead.
Besides, `withName` is not called anyways in your example, so shouldn't be mocking the class be enough or do you call the method later on?

Comment: It's not used in my example, because I need a mock. I don't want to explicitly use ```Fruit::withName('Apple');``` The mock would need to call that static method to return the object.

Comment: BTW, there is a term for your static "constructor" - _factory method_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPUnit used to support mocking static methods, but since PHPUnit 4.0 it's omitted. I see four options here:

**1. Don't mock the method at all**

You could just call the method and use it's logic, although you'd test the static method as well if you do and normally that's something you should avoid when writing unit tests.

**2. Change the class**

Ask yourself if this method really needs to be static and if not, change the class to test it properly. There are quite some use cases where it's better to change some of your architecture in order to write proper tests.

**3. Use a spy class**

Spy classes are classes that extend a class that you would usually mock, but implement some logic for testing the configuration of a class or the dependency of a tested method to another method. In the very most cases this can be avoided by mocking the class properly. Spies are simply your work around if mocks are not enough, there are very few cases in which you really need them.

However, in this case a spy could be used to overwrite a static method as a work around:

```
class FruitSpy extends Fruit
{

    public static $return;

    public static $name;

    public static function withName($name) {
        $expected = self::$name;
        if($name == $expected) {
            return self::$return;
        } else {
            throw new \RuntimeException("FruitSpy::withName(): Parameter 0 was $name, $expected expected");
        }
    }

}
```

This example checks for the correct `$name` and, if it's correct, returns your defined return. You'd use it like this in your test:

```
$fruitSpy = new FruitSpy();
$fruitSpy::$name = "Banana";
$fruitSpy::$return = new \stdClass();

$this->fruitSalad->addFruit($fruitSpy);
```

Not exactly a clean solution, but the only way I see if you absolutely positively don't want to change other code than the test code.

Again, you should think about changing the static method to a casual method if you need to do something like this.

**4. Use PHPUni 3.***

You could simple use a deprecated version of PHPUnit to use this method. Not a preferred way either.

**Conclusion**

I don't see a clean way to mock a static method and `::staticExpects()` was removed for a reason in 4.0

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a mock for Fruit using the static named constructor?

You can't. Mocks are created by using a mocking framework.

Anyway it does not matter how mocks are created but, instead, how they behave, because they're external to the class being tested.

Just configure the mock so that it behaves the same way a real Fruit instance would when created using `Fruit::withName`.